# Adding Custom transition effect to jCarousel Smooth Slider Wordpress Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jcarousel

The [Smooth Slider wp Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/smooth-slider/) uses the jquery.jcarousel.min.js for transition effects. The problem is that it contains a single type of transition (the default): swing.

Can someone please guide me into how I can change the transition type to something like fading? From what I've read, I have to use the *.animate()* function from jQuery, more specifically the **easing** attribute.

I understand that it must be done using the jQueryUI, maybe adding plugins to existing jQuery?  The problem is I am a total noob with jQuery and would really appreciate some guidance.

Here is the slider which I would like to customize: http://brainconcert.com/minovici/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure but I believe you can utilize the properties from jCarousel by using *jquery.jcarousel.min.js*.

Those (and the details) can be found [**here**](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/).

What you can do to test this is find code similar to this in your `<head>`:

```
    <!--START: Carousel-->
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel();
    jQuery('.multi-carousel').jcarousel({
        easing: 'easeOutBounce',
        animation: 750,
        scroll: 4,
        visible: 0,
        auto: 0,
        wrap: 'last',
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
    });
        });
</script>
<!--END: Carousel-->
```

Utilize the `easing:` property.

If this doesn't work, don't remove the easing property just yet.  Instead, place the easing query plugin [**found here**](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Easing) on your server and call it in your `<head>` like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="folder/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
```

If you set your easing property, called to that plugin and included the latest jQuery library it should work.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I managed to add the plugin to my website, and indeed now I can switch to the existing easing effects.

Comment: One more thing, do you happen to know how I can set the last slide to have the same swing effect when going back to the first one (now it just passes back through all the other slides).

For example... the slider automatically goes from 1 to 2, then to 3, 4 and 5... and when it reaches the last one (5) it goes back to slide 1 like such: 5-4-3-2-1. I'm looking for it to just go from 5 to 1 the standard way. 

Is there any attribute from jCarousel or jQuery that I should set-up?

Answer (score 0):

If you add `wrap: 'circular'` to your jCarousel `<head>` tag, you'll be able to have it transition from 5 to 1... how to make this work with easing I'm not entirely sure.

Check out the source of the [**jCarousel circular page**](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_circular.html).

Also - a lot of different jCarousel examples (with code to pull in the source) [**here**](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/).

Good luck